# Android taking too long to recycle bitmaps onDestroy

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am working with a lot of bitmaps in my game for android and everything works great, but when I click a button to start new activity, the game freezes for about half a second. It's not much, but it's annoying. In the onDestroy method I recycle all the bitmaps, to save memory an this cause the application to freeze. Is there any smarter solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try recycling them in an asynctask when onDestroy is called

Something like this

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    new AsyncTask<Bitmap[],Void,Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap[]... params) {
            for (Bitmap b : params[0]) {
                b.recycle();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(bitmaps);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me more details about this?

Comment: The `AsyncTask` can run in the background even after the `Activity` that it is called from is destroyed. Because `AsyncTask` runs in the background, `onDestroy()` will not block and the new `Activity` will be launched much quicker.